# jQuery 'this' following a .find click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need some help with this one...I have the following javascript code:

```
        var quickSection = $('.quick-links');
        var quickContent = $('.quick-links .row .inner-content')

        if ( quickSection.is('*') ) {

            quickContent.find("img").click(function() {
                $(this).find("ul").slideDown("slow");
            });
        }
```

There are three instances of my variable quickContent.  Each have a ul, img, etc.  I need to display the ul that correlates with the image that is clicked.  I thought the above code would do the trick, but I suppose that 'this' is also returning the '.find(img)' from the previous line.  Any tips as to how I can solve this in the most efficient manner?  Any help is much appreciated.

html:

```
<div class="quick-links block">
        <div class="main-wrap container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 first column">
                    <div class="inner-content">
                        <h2>Admissions<a><img src="/sites/all/themes/merge/img/blue-down.png" /></a></h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a>Apply Now</a></li>
                            <li><a>Schedule a Visit</a></li>
                            <li><a>Student Life</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!--end inner-content-->
                </div><!--end col-->
                <div class="col-sm-4 second column">
                    <div class="inner-content">
                        <h2>Academics<a><img src="/sites/all/themes/merge/img/green-down.png" /></a></h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a>A Liberal Arts Degree</a></li>
                            <li><a>College of Arts &amp; Sciences</a></li>
                            <li><a>College of Business</a></li>
                            <li><a>College of Health Sciences</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!--end inner-content-->
                </div><!--end col-->
                <div class="col-sm-4 third column">
                    <div class="inner-content">
                        <h2>Student Life<a><img src="/sites/all/themes/merge/img/gold-down.png" /></a></h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a>Campus Photo Tour</a></li>
                            <li><a>Student Organizations</a></li>
                            <li><a>Residence Life</a></li>
                            <li><a>Facilities</a></li>
                            <li><a>Food &amp; Drink</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!--end inner-content-->
                </div><!--end col-->
            </div><!--end row-->
        </div><!--end container-->
    </div><!--end quick-links-->
```

Comment: `this` in an event handler is the target of the event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` will be the image that was clicked on, not an element of `quickContent`. You need to go up to the container and then search down for the corresponding `ul`.

```
quickContent.find("img").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".inner-content").find("ul").slideDown("slow");
}
```

Or if they're both children of the same element, you can use:

```
quickContent.find("img").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings("ul").slideDown("slow");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfect!  Another question I have is... what is the most efficient way to collapse the current ul if another 'inner-content' img is clicked.  I am currently adding a class and the checking if it has class, but this seems way too much for a simple task.  Is there a more efficient/better way to do this that you know of?

Comment: Hard to say for sure if there's a better way without seeing the actual code.

Comment: Same code as above.  I added the html to the original post.  I need the open 'ul' to close if another is opened with the function you provided.

Comment: `$("ul.classname").slideUp("slow").removeClass("classname");`

Answer (score 0):

You can include `img` in your selector like:

```js
var quickSection = $('.quick-links');

if (quickSection.is('*')) {
  $('.quick-links .row .inner-content img').click(function() {
    $(this).parents("h2").next("ul").slideDown("slow");
  });
}
```

Comment: I don't think that will work as the ul is not a child of the image.  Probably my fault for not including my html.  Ive added it to the original post

Comment: @user3633970 change it after you include html.

Answer (score 0):

.parent() will do the trick, as it changes the current scope to the div containing your clicked image.

```
 var quickSection = $('.quick-links');
        var quickContent = $('.quick-links .row .inner-content')

        if ( quickSection.is('*') ) {

            quickContent.find("img").click(function() {
                $(this).parent().find("ul").slideDown("slow");
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you attach a click handler to an element, `$(this)` will refer to the clicked element; so the image, in this case. Since you have multiple jQuery objects in `quickContent`, you'll probably have to traverse back up the the DOM tree to find the one you need. Something like:

```
quickContent.find("img").click(function(){
  $(this).parents('.quick-links .row .inner-content').find("ul").slideDown("slow");
}
```

There may well be a more efficient way, depending on your exact DOM structure. For instance, the jQuery functions `.next()`, `.prev()`, or `.siblings()` might be useful.